# How to compare javadoc jars to analyze changes?

Tags: javadoc

I want to compare the javadoc across different releases .
I am exploring jDiff - but facing issues with the command line version - SAX Parser not found.
Does anyone have insights on the same?

Are there any other tools using which I can achieve the same?

Thanks
Mrinal

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5337179/524900)